# Firebase - different urls for for account management features

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

Currently **firebase** offers pretty easy the management of user accounts like: **Email verification**, **password recovery**, **changing email account**. And for that we can set a custom url to redirect the user after the acc management process. Like that:
[image]

Now is it possible to set different urls for different management-features? For instance, I want to redirect the user to another url after verifying his acc than for resetting his password. Because when I change the url for email-verification it automatically changes the url for resetting the password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to have a landing page for all these actions, and redirect from the landing page depends on the different email actions. [Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler) is the guide of how to do that.